# how can I get my puppy to transition from potty pad to outside

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, toilet-training

My 5 month old husky puppy refuses to go potty outside. When we first got her she went potty outside just fine and a week after we got her she got parvo and when she got over it the vet told us that she couldn't go outside for a week so we had her go on puppy pads. When we take her outside she refuses to go and once we get in the house she goes to the bathroom in the spot were the pad used to be. I have already tried moving the pad close to the door, I have tried taking her out every 30 minutes, I wait 30 minutes after she eats and then take her outside, I even have sat outside for half an hour and she still holds it and when we put her in her kennel for an hour or so she pees in her kennel. What do I do to get her to go potty outside?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [How do I transition my dog from using potty pads to going outside?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1277)

Answer (score 6):

Dogs go where they are used to so this behavior is not surprising. The good thing is that she's very young so it will be easier than with an older dog and that he's gotten the all clear to go outside! Transitioning from one spot to another is generally very similar to potty training the first time.

Moving the pads closer to the door is a good idea. You could try moving the "spot" where she goes over time. Here are some other tips:

Take a soiled pad outside and put it on the ground. The smell may encourage her to go in a new spot.

Only spend about 5 minutes outside. If she doesn't go then, put her back in her crate. This isn't a reward or a punishment, but simply to make it less likely she goes inside. Take her out again about 10 min. later and then praise her when she goes. This works best when you know for sure she needs to go.

Timing for rewarding successes can vary for each dog. Generally relieving oneself is reward in itself and excess emotions my frighten the puppy so that they stop. Some dogs need a little more encouragement during or directly after. Remember rewards can be events so running back to the house to play a game is perfectly acceptable here.

Make the crate as small as possible to prevent her to soiling her crate. Then make it even smaller. At this time, it should be just big enough for them to walk in a lie down.

Since she's learned on pads, don't worry if it takes a little while for her to get the transition. She's still young and will figure it out soon enough.

Comment: Great answer. Also do not give her access to the old potty spot... close the bathroom door. You could also use tether training so that she is always attached to you when inside if she isn't in her crate. That will probably be the fastest though it takes a little getting used to.