# Will putting my dog's poo outside encourage it to take a dump in the garden?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

My puppy (10 weeks, Pembrokeshire Corgi) has been having a little trouble with toilet training. He's only managed to poo once in the garden and all other instances have been indoors.

He's very good at using his puppy pads, so I've tried putting a few outside. However, he still just plays outside and then goes inside, goes crazy and does a poo.

Would taking some of his poo and putting it outside (burying, covering it) encourage him to poo outside?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I transition my dog from using potty pads to going outside?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1277)