# How to make my dog pee inside our apartment

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, crossbreed

One year ago we adopted a small female dog that we named Lola. At that time she was 1 and half years old, so now she is 2 and a half. Lola was abandoned with her puppies before being rescued. She lived for some time on a farm with other dogs and cats, probably with a lot of space to run freely.

<del>She is a very afraid dog. She has fear of buses, people, leaves on the ground, plastic bags, brooms, thunders and so. She is a small mixed-breed dog.</del>

By the time of the adoption, the previous owners told us that Lola was taught to not pee or poop inside the house. It's been one year now and we have tried some tricks, but with no success. We tried:

1. defining a place where she could do pee, first with journal papers, a "kind-of-a-diaper-sheet";
2. dropped a few drops of a special product that makes dog pee on paper;
3. collected her own pee and the pee of other dogs with those papers so she could understand that she can use that space to pee;
4. tried to teach command words while she was outside to make her pee or poop on demand (like a lot of videos on YouTube)

Nothing did work. Also on some days, she stays almost 10h alone at home, without peeing.

Do you guys have other ideas on how to succeed in this task?

**EDIT**

I am removing the "fear dog" part because I added it as a contextualization for the question, but it didn't work as expected. The main question remains: how to make my dog pee inside.

Comment: Why would you want the dog to pee in the house? If the dog can hold it for the time you're not at home (which isn't unrealistic), there shouldn't be a problem. If the dog really has to pee, it will, no matter the circumstances.

Comment: a dog needs fresh air every day so i think you shuld try to solve this in an other way,please talk to your vet about the dogs fear of the outside world.

Comment: @Mario Maybe it's raining outside, or we are without electricity (and we have to carry her 10 floors down and up), or we want her to feel comfortable.

Comment: rain or shine, it's your duty as a dog owner to walk your dog. This is about YOUR comfort, not your dog's.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jwenting! After almost 5 years, a lot has changed. We adopted another dog and although they both don't pee inside our apartment, we are still walking 3x a day with them, with rain or sun. And this is also about their comfort, by allowing them to pee whenever they want, not only when we walk them outside.

Answer (score 3):

Some lessons are really difficult to unlearn.  This is one of them. Rather then trying to unlearn don't go potty inside, teach a new lesson.

Work on the reverse of my answer at the question below. Teach your dog to use a potty pad outside. Once that lesson is learned, you then transition to the potty pad being indoors and being used.

Alternately there are a range of products that are 'indoor grass potties for dogs' these can be made or purchased.  And might be a better solution.

Related [How do I transition my dog from using potty pads to going outside?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-transition-my-dog-from-using-potty-pads-to-going-outside)

Comment: It is unnatural for a housebroken dog to change his trained behavior. Untrained puppies and some dogs with behavioral issues will continue to pee inside. However a housebroken dog has been trained to go outside. He was punished for going inside. You are asking him to unlearn a behavior that he was punished for doing before. Your dog is confused. I think what you are trying to do is for your convenience not his. Imagine you being asked you to do the reverse of what you were brought up to do. Would you not be confused? My guess is if you continue you will cause more behavioral issues.

Comment: @LearnedMan are you trying to post this comment on my answer or the question?

Answer (score 1):

My dog, a small mixed breed feared the outside when I got him. He was a rescue dog. It took time and understanding w/reassurance that it was ok. Just go to dogs level and rub both ears saying softly something soothing like its ok, youll be ok, that type of stuff. Its been 4 years and Patch is much better with less visanle fear. As for peeing in the house, try to walk her every day until she goes exclusively outside. You dont want your dog to go indoors...

Comment: I am sorry if you didn't understand the question. She already goes exclusively outside to pee or poop. Now I would like to know, why you don't like your dog going indoors?