# How can I get our puppy to learn new house breaking skills?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, crate

Our Coton de Tuléar, named Ruby, is 4.5 months old. We thought we did well limiting her space to the kitchen and providing a small area outside her crate (where she sleeps) for elimination. Initially, she eliminated half the time on pad and half the time on kitchen floor - rarely outside. Often some "excitement" pee occurs when we first let her out of the crate, but I'm not counting that.

Now, she NEVER goes outside, rarely goes on pad, but goes very close to where her fenced barrier was in the kitchen.  We are trying to attempt behavioral reset in that regard.  So I removed the barrier in kitchen, and the pads.  I'm taking her out first thing in the morning, and every hour, but she sits on lawn doing nothing, then pees on the floor the minute she's back in the house.  I don't even get a chance to praise and give treats outside because she WON'T go outside!  I'm feeling really desperate and hopeless. It feels like we will never get her sorted.

I'm wondering if I move her crate to the laundry room and don't allow her in the kitchen, maybe there will be a reset possibility?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I transition my dog from using potty pads to going outside?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-transition-my-dog-from-using-potty-pads-to-going-outside)

Comment: In addition to the linked answer you need to clean her "potty spot" with an enzyme cleaner to remove the smell of pee. This lingering smell tells her "here's the toilet, don't do it anywhere else", so you need to chemically destroy the smell.

Comment: Maybe you could even create a new potty spot in your yard by smearing a used potty pad against a stone or tree trunk. I strongly advice against marking a wall or evergreen as potty spot, because the wall will stain and stink and evergreens have a tendency to wither and die when dogs pee on them.

Comment: Thank you for responding!  I wish I had saved the last used pee pad...I didn't and I'm concerned that re-introducing it will confuse her even more.  Last night she pooped in her crate which I always read dogs will avoid at all costs.  We had taken her on a walk before "bed time" but she did nothing on the walk.